# Regex to evaluate Date Range

Tags: regex, date, pattern-matching, range, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a UNIX ls output and have to write a regex to return filenames for date range greater than 2017-11-05.

I know regex is not for numerical evaluation, but the tool I am using only support patterns, and that's why my only option is regex.

Sample input is as below:

https://regex101.com/r/shFymy/2

> drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 05:10 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-15
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:35 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-16
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 21:54 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-17
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 23:59 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-18
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 21:49 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-19
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:32 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-20
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 11:51 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-21
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:08 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-22
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 22:42 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-23
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:58 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-24
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 05:10 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-25
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:46 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-26
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:04 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-27
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:46 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-28
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 00:21 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-29
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 05:09 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-30
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 05:13 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-10-31
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 14:34 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-01
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 09:20 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-02
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 14:35 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-03
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:42 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-04
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-02 09:18 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-05
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:11 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-06
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 17:56 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-07
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 21:36 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-08
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 16:43 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-09
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-01-31 21:59 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-10
>   drwxrwxr-x   - testetl hdp_test          0 2018-02-01 09:23 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-11

Sample output is as below:

> drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-02-01 09:11 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-06 drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-01-31 17:56 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-07 drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-01-31 21:36 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-08 drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-01-31 16:43 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-09 drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-01-31 21:59 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-10 drwxrwxr-x - testetl hdp_test 0 2018-02-01 09:23 /raw/ADS/ClicksData/click/datetm=2017-11-11

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cdi7YE/1

Comment: What is the tool you use to perform this task ? 
You mention snowflake-datawarehouse - are you're using Snowflake? 
If so, how's the input stored in a table? One record per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, might be what you're asking.

Note this isn't a *date validation*.
It's just a greater than date validation.
A lot more intense regex stuff (including leap year) is needed to
validate the date. But, I don't presume this is what you need.

https://regex101.com/r/AE0g7o/1

`(?m)^.*(?:(?:201[89]|2\d[2-9]\d|[3-9]\d{3})-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|2017-(?:12-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|11-(?:0[6-9]|[12]\d|3[01])))$`

Note, you can make it shorter if you replace all the 01 - 31 and 01 - 12 with just \d{2}

Formatted

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode 
 ^                             # BOL
 .* 
 (?:
      (?:                           # 2018 - 9999
           201 [89] 
        |  2 \d [2-9] \d 
        |  [3-9] \d{3} 
      )
      -                            
      (?: 0 [1-9] | 1 [0-2] )       # 01 - 12
      - 
      (?:                           # 01 - 31
           0 [1-9]                     
        |  [12] \d 
        |  3 [01] 
      )
   |                              # OR,

      2017                          # 2017
      -
      (?:
           12 -                          # 12    
           (?:                           # 01 - 31
                0 [1-9]                     
             |  [12] \d 
             |  3 [01] 
           )

        |                              # or,
           11 -                          # 11
           (?:                           # 06 - 31
                0 [6-9] 
             |  [12] \d 
             |  3 [01] 
           )
      )
 )
 $                             # EOL
```

---

Shortened version, still only validates greater than date

`(?m)^.*(?:(?:201[8-9]|2\d[2-9]\d|[3-9]\d{3})-\d{2}-\d{2}|2017-(?:12-\d{2}|11-(?:0[6-9]|[12]\d|3[01])))$`

https://regex101.com/r/wtL0Hx/1

Comment: Thanks, date validation is not a requirement, I was only looking for greater than dates.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return a whole line that ends with a date later than November 5th 2017, you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/shFymy/4):

```
^.*=(?:2017-(?:11-(?:0[6-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|12-\d{2})|2018-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

It matches in 3 cases:

- Dates in November 2017, starting from the 5th and further
- Dates in December 2017
- Dates in 2018

You were'nt specific about the correctness of the input, so I assumed all dates are valid (i.e. not `2018-45-90`)

Comment: November has 30 days, not 31

Comment: You are including the 5th, the OP says greater than the 5th.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too hard on yourself by trying to use regexp. Not sure what tool you're using, but I'm sure there are other options:

- If it's anything like a shell script, just convert input dates to Unix timestamps, e.g.

  ```
  $ date -u -d '2017-11-06' +%s
  1509926400
  ```

  and then you have a number you can easily compare with a constant
- Another option, remove dashes from `2017-11-06`:

  ```
  $ echo '2017-01-06' | tr -d '-'
  20170106
  ```

  Again, the output is comparable as a simple integer
- If you're using Snowflake (you added the `snowflake-datawarehouse` label), just do

  ```
  SELECT SUBSTR(line, -10)::date
  ```

  and you have a date you can compare

Btw, the more details you provide, the better answer you'll get.

Comment: Thanks, but while creating snowflake stage, you can't use any of the above.

Comment: Oh. In that case you might be right. Then the solution by Gal Abra should work. You might want to raise a feature request for more flexible filtering in Snowflake forums.